# Site Content Types are Missing

Tags: content-type

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hidden content types](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45128/hidden-content-types)

We had an issue of content types in one of our site collections. We have lost the default content types from all our sites. We don't have server access since our site is stored in the cloud. So what are the possible ways to get back the content types available? Please provide me suggestions.